# How to write compactly $c_1^T \nabla c_2^T \nabla c_3^T \nabla c_4^T \nabla ... c_k^T \nabla f(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

Let $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k$ be a collection of $k$ column vecotrs in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.   We are interested in
\begin{align*}
c_1^T \nabla c_2^T \nabla c_3^T \nabla c_4^T \nabla ... c_k^T \nabla f(x)
\end{align*}
where $\nabla$ is the gradient operator.

**Question:** Can this be written more compactly?  Perhaps by using Hadamard product or some other matrix form.

Comment: You can write this as $n$ nested sums with the $n$th order partial derivatives in the summand, but it's not much prettier. Start with one and two gradients to see what happens. Where does this come from, and why do you want to simplify this?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Do yo mean like this $\sum_{m_1}^n ... \sum_{m_k}^n  c_{1,m_1}  c_{2,m_2} ...c_{1,m_k} \frac{\partial^k }{\partial  t_{m_1} ... \partial t_{m_k}} f(t)$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Sorry. I mean something like  this $\sum_{m_1=1}^n ... \sum_{m_k=1}^n  c_{1,m_1}  c_{2,m_2} ...c_{k,m_k} \frac{\partial^k }{\partial  t_{m_1} ... \partial t_{m_k}} f(t)$

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut LIke you said this not very compact. I was wondering if this can be written in some kind of matrix multiplication form?